# IP RemoteEndPoint block by text received

Tags: c#

I created a TCP listener that I receive from client the IP and HWID from pc. Now I want  the listener to block ip received from client by hiwd received and saved in a text file. Is that possible? Here is the listener code.

```
tcpListener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, 8000);
listenThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(ListenForClients));
listenThread.Start();

private static void HandleClientComm(object client)
{
    TcpClient tcpClient = (TcpClient)client;
    //   NetworkStream clientStream = tcpClient.GetStream();
    clientStream = tcpClient.GetStream();

    byte[] message = new byte[65536];
    int bytesRead;

    bytesRead = 0;

    // Blocks until a client sends a message      

    bytesRead = clientStream.Read(message, 0, message.Length);
    {
        // Message has successfully been received
        ASCIIEncoding encoder = new ASCIIEncoding();

        // Output message
        string hwidban = File.ReadAllText("hwid.txt");

        if (encoder.GetString(message, 0, bytesRead) == hwidban)
        {
        //BLOCK IP CODE

        }
        else
        {

        //Console.WriteLine("To: " + tcpClient.Client.LocalEndPoint);
        textFromClient = ("IP at:  " + tcpClient.Client.RemoteEndPoint + " HardwareID:" + encoder.GetString(message, 0, bytesRead));

            //Console.WriteLine(encoder.GetString(message, 0, bytesRead));

        } while (clientStream.DataAvailable) ;

        // Release connections
        //  clientStream.Close();

        //tcpClient.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Why so much break lines in your code?

Comment: It was test codes ther and after delete I didn't delete break lines to.

Comment: Have you considered using the async methods for communication?

Comment: @RudiVisser : I'm open for any sugestion but I'm not familiar with async methods.

Comment: I would suggest learning/using them here. If you don't want your code to block, your only real options are to stick that blocking on a background thread (which is somewhat inefficient), or use the async methods which do that internally.